# Padding in python and Tor proxy

Tags: python, padding, tor

I'm having a problem with padding in python but only if I connect to server with tor proxy, if I connect from the client to the server everything goes ok. 
In particular when I try to download a file, either big or small, it write a 0 byte file and close the session with an error in b64decode..

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding
```

Comment: Your source is not valid Base 64. Cannot help without further information.

Comment: Well you should probably post what you're trying to decode to begin with and perhaps try to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish so that we can try to replicate the problem.

Comment: I can't post what I'm trying to decode because the data come from a connection and not from a file. What I'm trying to accomplish is to make a peer-to-peer connection from a server to a client with a program coded in python, the data are encrypted with AES-256 and encoded with "Base 64". If I connect from one point to the other one through Tor I can't do anything because of an error with "padding" but I don't thing that the problem is with "padding" because if I connect from one point to the other one without Tor I can do everything, upload download etc..